# How to export/convert WhatsApp chat to PDF/Excel/HTML?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

How do I convert/export WhatsApp chat (by chat person/group) to PDF/Excel/ HTML so that I can open it in a computer? I've tried several methods:

1. Manual way using screenshot and stitching it using Android app. To be honest, I really don't want using this method. It's the most cumbersome way.
2. The preferred way, using an app called [Backup Text for Whats](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.smeiti.wstotext). This app is the one that has the most feature that I know about. It can filter to backup WhatsApp chat based on person/group chat, and can even convert all your chat to the desired format. It can convert to HTML (which can then be converted to PDF including the images downloaded), Excel (and download images separately), or even text. It's most versatile app that I know about when it comes to backing up whatsapp messages. You needed to install Tri-Crypt first to use it. My Android is 4.2, but now with the current WhatsApp version, it is not functioning. I don't know why.

Does anyone know any other method? Has anybody tried Backup Text for Whats app and why is it not functioning anymore?

Note: whatever the method, it should maintain how it is displayed in WhatsApp, if possible.

Comment: This can be done beautifully using a software called Snagit by TechSmith. [This video shows how to do it.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MXbRkJKRVZg).

Answer (score 7):

Fortunately for you, WhatsApp actually has a built-in option for this. No need for third party apps!

WhatsApp has an option called "**email chat"** which converts your chat into a word document containing all conversation with a specific person or group.

Simply open WhatsApp, press on the conversation you'd like to backup. Open the menu on top right, press on "more" ->" email chat" it will ask you if you want to include your media or not. It will then bring you to your email app where you can select a recipient. You can choose yourself as the receiver. After you receive the email, You'll be able to open the conversation as a word document.

Depending on the app you use to view word documents, you should have an option to save as PDF.

This is how it will be displayed in your word document:

> 2/2/18, 03:55 - smith: *text*
>
> 2/2/18, 03:55 - jack: *text*
>
> 2/2/18, 03:56 - Smith: *text*

Emojis will be included in the word document. Media and voice notes will be sent in a separate file.

Comment: Btw is there any reason why you don't use WhatsApp web to view your WhatsApp on a computer?

Comment: Yes I can screen capture it through computer. But it just image. Not searchable.

Comment: If I copy it by highlighting all the chat then put it to a word doc, it doesn't display like in the app.

Comment: Unfortunately, since ca. 2020, this is not possible with the German version anymore due to some weird lawsuit

Comment: This doesn't work at all.

Answer (score 4):

Not the Android stuff, but I wrote an extension for the Chrome browser that helps you save messages to your PC from WhatsApp Web.

If you check the ‘try grabbing media’ checkbox it will also fetch all the media that were ever sent in a chat.

It will create a ZIP archive with all your messages and media, easy to open and read in your browser. It will have the same look as WhatsApp Web.

Here’s the link to the extension: [Backup WhatsApp Chats Chrome Store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/backup-whatsapp-chats/gmbicfpadlmgkfhfepknbmemfhahelll)
If it doesn't work, you can try a developer version [Backup WhatsApp Chats Dev version](https://chatsaver.org/files.html)

Comment: Extension isn't free ^^

Comment: @GFoley83 The author of the question did mention that it has to be free. 

@ tube-builder This extension is working well.

Comment: Yes @Peter, that's why I said the extension isn't free?!

Answer (score 0):

Dude, I was looking for answer *similar* to your question, and what I just figured out, that works at least for me, is is via directly selecting the text in the chat I want to export, and then click on the **"print"** option.

You know... like printing to a pdf file.

It worked just fine to export the ***formatted text*** (that was what I was looking for specifically)

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about Excel, but WhatsApp allows you to export an individual or group chat to a text file. You just need to open a conversation that you'd like to export and tap More > Export Chat. Then, you can open the text file with MS Word and save it as PDF or html. Please note that formatting will get little messed up.

If you'd like to directly export WhatsApp conversations to a PDF or HTML, you will need a a third party desktop application like the one mentioned [in this guide](https://www.iphone-to-pc.com/export-whatsapp-messages-to-pdf-iphone-android.html). Your chats will be displayed in a similar way they appear on the WhatsApp messenger app. I personally tried it to document and print my WhatsApp conversations for some legal problem. This is how it works:

- Install the app on your Windows computer on Mac.
- Enable the USB debugging mode on the Android device.
- Backup all the chats to your phone's storage or SD card.
- Connect your phone to your computer and let the load your WhatsApp
  conversation.
- Right-click on the conversation you'd wish to export and select
  "Export messages to file."

**Note**: I have no affiliation with the linked product. The software is paid. With the free version, you can only export a couple of messages per conversation/contact. You need to put the software to export more messages.

Answer (score 0):

You can Export the Conversation to .txt file from within WhatsApp.

And then this web app can load the conversation file and "re-generate" the look and feel to rebuild the conversation, and even replay it back.

**Chat Viewer for Whatsapp:** 
https://overbits.herokuapp.com/chatviewer/

You can even tweak the look and feel if you know how to Right Click -> Inspect Element and play with the CSS values in your browser.