# How to view/filter posts by a user in a WhatsApp group?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

I am a participant in a WhatsApp group for a long time. I want to view all posts I have done in the WhatsApp group.

How to view/filter them?

Comment: The official WhatsApp app doesn't really provide such a feature. I think the alternative is to [export the conversation](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/190505/44325) and filter them externally.

Answer (score 1):

Go to telegram
Create an empty group.
Go to whatsapp group you want to filter messages of.
3 dots > Export chat > including media > Telegram group that you just made

All the Chat's will be exported and then you may filter it by the users. Screenshots below

Downsides?

- you will not be able to see the tagged messages
- some stickers (but not all) won't appear if it isn't added in telegram. As seen in the screenshots
- there will be numbers instead of name (if the contact is not on telegram, I guess)

[image]

[image]

Upvote if you find this helpful:)
Thanks!